# How do I use an index that has dots in the name?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm just starting to learn the Cypher query language and GraphDb in general. I've created some indexes using the class name of my nodes like:
"com.acme.node.SomeNodeType"

I can't for the life of me figure out how to reference this index in Cypher. I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/_TYclxVzPjw) but using ` didn't work for me.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to use an index with dots in the name?
2. If so, how do I specify the name in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try to query them with '' like

```
start n = node:`my.index`('name:test') return n
```

?

Comment: Thanks Peter. That got me closer:
START n = node:`my.index`('name:Test') works, but once I add a space in the query like ('name:Test Testdude') I get "Invalid Query".

Comment: Ah! ('name:"Test Testdude")  Thanks Peter